# Create a Travel Request form in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: workflow, custom-form

I want to develop a travel request form in which the user will provide all details and will submit request for traveling. On submission a workflow will be started and it needs to be approved from 5-6 approvers one after another.

I searched that, I can use existing facility like Task - in which I will modify the columns as per my need and treat each request as 1 task. But in that case the look and feel of task is traditional SharePoint look..while I want to design the fields to look it like the current hard copy of form they are using.

As I need to use SharePoint foundation I can not use InfoPath. Please suggest any good way to develop such custom form and apply workflow on it. I also need to show each request on Dashboard like it shows Announcements and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the display form of the task list using SharePoint Designer. This will allow you to recreate your travel request form as needed. One note, the existing for web part that's on the display form, keep it, just hide it using web part properties, then add a new one that you can modify. If you remove it bad things happen.

Alternatively you can create a custom application (ASP.Net) page with Visual Studio, which can provide much more functionality, but will be a higher level of effort.

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much David, I will try this and will get back if any other details are needed

Comment: Hi David..did you mean the way explained in this post http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010378258.aspx

Comment: Yes! That should do it for you.